# Is a symmetrical fair odd-faced die posssible?

Tags: probability, geometry

I can't come up with a scenario for a 5-faced die, but maybe 9 or 27 is possible?

Comment: Why not double the number of sides and write each number twice?

Comment: Hi and welcome! How do you imagine a 5 faced (fair) die like?...

Comment: No this is for calculating the EV of an n sided die. If a symmetric odd-faced die is possible then only the even case matters.

Comment: For clarity I meant to say faced.

Comment: What makes a die fair?  Is it sufficient that each face subtends an equal solid angle from the centroid?

Comment: It should be possible to create a fair pyramid on a square base by adjusting the height - a very flat one would land about half the time on the square, and a very tall thin one would rarely land on the square. Somewhere in between, it would land one fifth of the time on the square. This would be symmetrical, but perhaps not in the way you meant.

Comment: Hm.  And maybe a fair die should have the identity as moment of inertia matrix; otherwise it'll prefer to spin on certain axes and thus, perhaps, prefer to land on certain faces.

Comment: Yes, I guess you could always make a die fair theoretically. I had to calculate the EV of an n-sided die in an interview yesterday with an option to roll again. When I got back to my room I realized it was different for even-faced die than odd-faced die. For even faced die it's option price is simply n/8. For odd-faced die it's ((n^2)-1)/(8n).

Comment: For calculating expected value, you don't need a physical die.  The computer can generate random numbers from $1$ to $n$ with a uniform distribution and you can calculate the expected value of that distribution.  But Mark Bennet is right, there must be a five sided pyramid that is fair.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Regular polyhedra must have tetrahedral, octahedral, or icosahedral symmetry.  These all require an even number of faces.

Additionally, dice formed by joining two congruent right pyramids each with a regular $n$-gon for a base has $2n$ faces, which is also even.  (The $D10$ die mentioned in the comments is two right pentagonal pyramids, for example.)

Comment: But for a fair die, it is not necessary to be a regular polyhedron. For example, a bipyramidal solid would be fair.